# Encrypt an Integer Value with DES

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, encryption-symmetric, des

I want to encrypt an integer with DES, the resultant cipher text should also be an integer.

Decryption function should follow this notion as well.

I am trying to modifying the code at [Encrypting a String with DES](http://exampledepot.com/egs/javax.crypto/DesString.html), by converting the byte array to integer, instead of using Base64 encoding. However the decryption function throws an exception of improper padding, as the conversion of integer to byte[] results in a 4 byte array.

Is there any other encryption algorithm that I can use to achieve this.

- I am not concerned about the weakness of the cipher text.

Comment: If you aren't concerned about security, why are you encrypting?  Also, no common encryption method can give a 4-byte output.

Comment: means to say that, I am not concerned about the chosen plain / cipher text attacks.

Comment: Why not? What are you defending against? Who are your attackers?

Comment: The integer value will be used as an exponent of BigInteger value, which will be used in the further processing of my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running an Integer value through DES to produce another Integer value, and you don't care about the cipher text weakness, then you are merely doing a very expensive hashing operation.  You'd be better off generating a random integer as the key and bitwise xor-ing the exponent and the random integer.  This would take nanoseconds to compute and have exactly the same security.

Answer (score 1):

DES has a 64 bit blocksize, so in general the output from the encryption of a 32 bit `int` will be a 64 bit block.  It will be easier to encrypt a 64 bit `long` to another 64 bit `long`.  Use ECB mode so that padding is not an issue, or at least you are adding zero bits to the front of your `int` to extend it to 64 bits.

If you merely want to smush up your `int` then Jim's suggestion is excellent.

Answer (score 1):

You want to look at [Format Perserving Encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption). There are a couple of techniques for it, but in general all of them will generate a value in the same domain as your input ( i.e. integers, credit card numbers,etc)